# map and hotspot in Ren'py

Tags: python, user-interface, renpy

I'm trying to make a map for my novel. But I ran into the problem that the hotspot is calling on other buildings, and I have a question, is it possible to make a hotspot in the form of a polygon?
Here is my code and maps:

```
screen map:
    imagemap:
        ground 'images/maps/morning/morning_ground.png'
        idle 'images/maps/morning/morning_idle.png'
        hover 'images/maps/morning/morning_hover.png'

        hotspot (690, 70, 200, 185) action Return("university")
        hotspot (528, 100, 120, 90) action Return("my house")


label charapter1:

    scene black with dissolve
    "Oh, finally I woke up, I had such a terrible dream"
    'Must hurry, otherwise I will be late, we must look at the map'
    window hide None
    call screen map
    window show None
    if _return == 'university':
        'Damn, I'm still late'
        return
    if _return == 'my house':
        'Why did I come home?'
        return
```

Images: [morning_hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZnN.png), [morning_idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIIa2.png), [morning_ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlL7.png)

Comment: It seems to me that it is easier to replace the hotspot with the imagebutton

Answer (score 0):

It seems image buttons are a better option for what you're looking for.

Draw the polygon you want in any software then use the following code:

```
imagebutton:
                idle the_button_you_drew.png
                hover (im.MatrixColor(the_button_you_drew.png, im.matrix.brightness(0.25)))
                action Jump("a_label_you_want")
```

It takes the same shape and size of the image you use. I'd recommend the background of that image to be transparent.